Dockerfile Not Found During Deployment to Render from GitHub Repository
I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot application to Render using a Dockerfile. My Dockerfile is located at the root of my project directory, but I am encountering an error during the deployment process.

Steps Taken:
1- Verified that the Dockerfile is named Dockerfile and is located in the root directory of the project.
2- Tested the Dockerfile locally using docker build -t quantumweb ., which works without issues.
Despite these steps, I still encounter the error where the Dockerfile cannot be found during the deployment process. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.


Hi maybe you can check in Github/Gitlab whether you've committed the Dockerfile.
Second check docker hub and see whether your Dockerfile is build and deploy there.
Make sure the docker that is deployed to docker hub must have the same name when you deploy it to Render.
Hope this helps :).
